# For Loop for excel data table in python

Tags: python, csv, for-loop, openpyxl

All,

I have a csv file that lists stocks and their data.  Column J in the Csv file shows their volume.  I am trying to use the below code to sort the data into a list with stocks that have a volume higher than 1,000,000.  However, when it prints the FirstList, it shows all stocks, including ones under the 1,000,000 rule.  Any ideas why?  Do I need to add Int or Float in my function?

```
FirstList = []
for i in range(5, 2000, 1):
    FirstList.append(int(sheet.cell(row=i, column=9).value))
    if (sheet.cell(row=i, column=9).value) > 1000000:
        FirstList.append(i)
print FirstList
```

Comment: `Do I need to add Int or Float in my function?` - Why not try that and see what happens?

Comment: I did but it gave me a bunch of errors

Comment: FirstList.append(int(sheet.cell(row=i, column=9).value))
  here you let execute that "append" any time it finds a row

Comment: Your first `.append` is adding *every* value from Column 9. Your second `append` (within the `if` block) is adding an index `i` based on column 8. If you're adding both the index `i`, *and* the value to the same list object, perhaps a list object is not what you need to be using... perhaps you don't understand what `append` is doing...

Comment: lemme get this straight... you want to append the value of column 9 to `FirstList` if the value of column 8 is greater than some value?

Comment: i see.  I want to keep the rows that have column J value of over 1,000,000 but its keeps all the rows

Comment: sorry guys, typo in the original question, both column numbers should be 9 not 8.

Comment: Is this about CSV or XLSX files?

Comment: this is for a csv file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This what you're going for?

```
FirstList = []
for i in range(5, 2000, 1):
    value = int(sheet.cell(row=i, column=9).value)
    if value > 1000000:
        FirstList.append(value)
print FirstList
```